# Why do many authors, when narrating a dialogue taking place in another language, use no contractions in English?

Tags: grammar, contractions

I have been reading a book lately in which the entire family speaks Vietnamese, but in order for the reader to understand, the dialogue is in English. However, it is written formally, with no contractions as I am writing to you right now.

My question is, why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a literary choice, not a matter of English usage standards,

Comment: Agreed with @Rob_Ster, but if this is an established and intentional literary technique, they might be able to tell you more about it at [Writers.se]. I think the answer is “English without contractions sounds quite unnatural, and this ongoing slight frisson as you read reminds you that you’re ‘not reading English’, but you’re ‘reading Vietnamese’ (or whatever other language)”. It’s a cheap and easy way for the reader to maintain consciousness of the fact that the dialog is occurring in another language.

Comment: It could be that the author is a lousy writer.  Many people shout when speaking to people with limited English.  It's not planned, and it's not smart or considerate. // Please, give us a link and a quote.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of what I explained.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is because every contraction is different and very different and it is very difficult for a person with English as second language to remember everything - unless the user is trained continuously from a small age through reading, writing, listening and speaking, and has people around to correct him/her.

Comment: To my reading, the question isn’t “Why do people who have English as a foreign language not use contractions in English”, but “Why, when [native speaking] writers, writing dialog which is intended to be understood to be taking in another language, but of course is actually written in English for pragmatic purposes, does that English dialog not contain contractions?”.

Comment: This is certainly a wrong answer — at best. It may also be an answer to another question, but it certainly isn't working here, noreven  vaguely true in the very least possible way.